# Genetic exercise of probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A homozygous recessive myopic woman (aa) marries a man with normal vision and they have 4 children. Taking into account that 76% of people with normal vision are heterozygous (Aa), calculate the probability that the two young children are myopic if one of the older ones is.

The answer is 0.25 but I don't understand why. Somebody could help me? Calculate that the probability of having a myopic child is 0'38 and of being normal 0'62 and that does give me good but this last one there is no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the man were normal vision and homozygous (AA) then all children would be normal vision heterozygous (Aa).  It would have been impossible for any of the children (*barring mutations*) to be myopic.

Since we are told that at least one of the older children is myopic, this directly informs us that the man is not (AA) and is instead (Aa).  This factoid about 76% of people with normal vision being heterozygous is unnecessary information that just gets in the way and likely caused your confusion.

We know then the wife is (aa) and the man is (Aa).  The older children are irrelevant at this point, they served their purpose in the problem in informing us that the man was not (AA) but was instead (Aa) and they are no longer relevant.

Now... each younger child will be myopic iff they receive the (a) allele from their father which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each.  They are guaranteed to receive an (a) allele from their mother.

Both having received an (a) allele from their father occurs then with probability:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} = 0.25$$

The point of this exercise was not only in testing your understanding of genetics and the passing on of traits, but also in testing your ability to recognize when certain information is irrelevant or unnecessary.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.